# When would you need SimpleInjector hybrid registration? (How can an object hosted in IIS be called without a HttpContext?)

Tags: c#, iis, dependency-injection, simple-injector

Following on from [my recent question regarding SimpleInjector and hybrid web request/thread lifestyles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687475/simpleinjector-mixed-lifestyle-for-per-web-request-and-lifetime-scope/14692613#14692613) it seems I do not fully understand the technical requirements and have been doing something I don't actually need to do.

With this code

```
interface IUnitOfWork { }
interface IWebUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork { }
interface IThreadUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork { }
class UnitOfWork : IWebUnitOfWork, IThreadUnitOfWork { }

container.RegisterPerWebRequest<IWebUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
container.RegisterLifetimeScope<IThreadUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
container.Register<IUnitOfWork>(() => container.GetInstance<UnitOfWork>());

// Register as hybrid PerWebRequest / PerLifetimeScope.
container.Register<UnitOfWork>(() =>
{
    if (HttpContext.Current != null)
        return container.GetInstance<IWebUnitOfWork>() as UnitOfWork;
    else
        return container.GetInstance<IThreadUnitOfWork>() as UnitOfWork;
});
```

My understanding was that for AppDomains running within IIS the `IWebUnitOfWork` would be returned, and otherwise there would be an error unless I have explicitly declared an instance of a LifetimeScope to wrap the call to the container (which would return `IThreadUnitOfWork`).

The following statement has made me realise I don't fully understand what I've been doing!

> You however, don't seem to need a hybrid lifestyle add all. A hybrid lifestyle is a lifestyle that can switch dynamically (on each call to GetInstance and per each injection), while you only seem to need to switch during start-up.

My question is this: under what circumstances can a container (or any other class for that matter), be it static or instance, that is loaded within an AppDomain running within IIS, be called without the existence of a HttpContext?

Comment: One thing that comes to mind is during startup. During the Application_Start event for instance, HttpContext.Current will be null. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I'm wondering when/how IThreadUnitOfWork could be returned if the container is running in IIS and therefore why we would need the hybrid registration to dynamically switch from one to the other.

Comment: Ach so. The HttpContext.Current is unavailable when you start a background thread. You could for instance run your commands asynchronously. In that case you need a lifetime scope. I would however advise to queue of commands to a Windows Service instead. You would typically use Lifetime Scope in a Windows Service as well.

Comment: Oh, I see!!! Yeah, as your answer to my last questions says - I don't need it! Thanks.

Comment: If you don't 'escape' from your HTTP request (by creating new threads, using the thread pool, or using the TPL) and run under IIS, there will always be a `HttpContext.Current` for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Steven has outlined in the comments, hybrid registration is generally needed when a web request can start a process on another thread. In this situation the container can be required to service requests for both Web Requests and Thread requests.